# android custom listview with gallery images

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, android-custom-view, android-image

I'm trying to add all the images contained in a folder in my custom listview, where I show a thumbnail of the photo and a little description.
I've found a lot of examples showing images from URL or drawable folder in Android Studio, but nothing working for me that loads a picture located in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/AAAAMMGG_HHMMSS.jpg

Here is my code - MainActivity:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

public int PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private Uri fileUri;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

TextView ceScanResults;
ImageButton btnScan;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    View addButton = findViewById(mci);
    ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listData));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem newsData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + newsData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    initViews();
}

private ArrayList<ListItem> getListData() {
    ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    String[] images = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.images_array);
    String[] headlines = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.headline_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
        newsData.setUrl(images[i]);
        newsData.setHeadline(headlines[i]);
        newsData.setReporterName("CE code");
        newsData.setDate("28/07/2015 - 10:31");
        listMockData.add(newsData);
    }
    return listMockData;
}

private void initViews() {
    //ceScanResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ceResults);
    btnScan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mci);
    btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void initGalleryFetchImage() {
    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    String filePath = null;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(selectedImage));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //use imageUri here to access the image
                selectedImageUri = fileUri;

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            selectedImageUri = intent.getData();

        }

        if(selectedImageUri != null){
            try {
                // OI FILE Manager
                String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                // MEDIA GALLERY
                String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                    filePath = selectedImagePath;
                } else if (filemanagerstring != null) {
                    filePath = filemanagerstring;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown path",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Bitmap", "Unknown path");
                }

                if (filePath != null) {
                    decodeFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    // bitmap = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.mci) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
        //create parameters for Intent with filename
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image captured by camera");
        //imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
        //create new Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    }
}
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try ( InputStream is = new URL(filePath).openStream() ) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
}
}
```

And the code of my CustomListAdapter:

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.reporterNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reporter);
            holder.reportedDateView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline());
        holder.reporterNameView.setText("" + newsItem.getReporterName());
        holder.reportedDateView.setText(newsItem.getDate());

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView reporterNameView;
        TextView reportedDateView;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
    }

My class ImageDownloaderTask:

    class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Drawable placeholder = imageView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeholder);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

My ListItem.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="icon"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks a lot for your precious support!
Greetings,
Michele.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this library to load images from an URL

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the exact way to access to my photos...they admits these:
"file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png" // from SD card
"file:///mnt/sdcard/video.mp4" // from SD card (video thumbnail)
"content://media/external/images/media/13" // from content provider
"content://media/external/video/media/13" // from content provider (video thumbnail)
"assets://image.png" // from assets
"drawable://" + R.drawable.img // from drawables (non-9patch images)

Answer (score 0):

try using code like this in Your adapter:

```
File img = new  File("/sdcard/image.jpg");

if(img.exists()){

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());

    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: I don't have any SD card, how can I solve this problem without it?

Comment: The code suggested doesn't load my image, it doesn't crash but I can't still see it in my list, how can I load my image located in /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/AAAAMMGG_HHMMSS.jpg
thanks!